# Script para restauración de bases de datos Con multiples MDF a una nueva locación

Tags: sql, sql-server, tsql

Me encuentro con un problema normal, restaurar bases de datos de un servidor a otro, y tengo un par de inconvenientes.

- Tengo que mover los mdf y los lds de locación.
- Son 10 Servidores con más de 80 BD cada uno.

He estado tratando de crear un script, que me permita generar los scripts de restauración, genero los backups, y los restauro, y bien. pero llegue a un punto donde me quede estancado, y por eso vine a pedir la ayuda de ustedes:

Este es mi Script:

```
DECLARE @folderpath VARCHAR (1000)
DECLARE @datapath VARCHAR (1000)
DECLARE @logpath VARCHAR (1000)
SELECT @folderpath = 'B:\'; -- Backup Location
SELECT @datapath = 'F:\SQL\DATA\'; -- Backup Location
SELECT @logpath = 'G:\SQL\LOG\'; -- Backup Location

SELECT 
        'RESTORE DATABASE['+d.NAME+'] FROM DISK = N ''' +@folderpath+d.name+'.bak'' WITH FILE = 1,
         MOVE N'''+f.name+''' TO N ''' +@datapath+d.name+ '_DATA.mdf'',
         MOVE N'''+f.name+''' TO N ''' +@logpath+d.name+ '_LOG.ldf'',
         NOUNLOAD, REPLACE, STATS = 10
         '
FROM sys.master_files f
INNER JOIN sys.databases d ON d.database_id = f.database_id
WHERE d.database_id > 4
GO
```

Acá estan los problemas con los que me he encontrado.

1- No he podido recuperar el nombre lógico del archivo ldf, puesto a que se lista en la siguiente fila.

2. Hay bases de datos que tienen más de 2 archivos mdf, por haría falta agregar otro MOVE.

Entiendo que es momento de utilizar conceptos mas avanzados, por lo que agradecería inmensamente si alguien me pudiera ayudar con lo que tengo pensado, para hacer el trabajo un poco más facil.

Muchas gracias comunidad.

Answer (score 0):

un amigo me ayudo con el tema, y claramente, era mucho más difícil de lo que pensé.

Acá la respuesta:

```
DECLARE @name VARCHAR(50) -- database name
DECLARE @conteo_arch vARCHAR(512) -- path for backup files
DECLARE @name_arch VARCHAR(512)
DECLARE @type_arch VARCHAR(50)
DECLARE @exten VARCHAR(50)
DECLARE @InicioCadena VARCHAR(1000)
DECLARE @datapath VARCHAR (1000)
DECLARE @logpath VARCHAR (1000)
DECLARE @bkpath VARCHAR (1000)

SELECT @datapath = 'F:\SQL\DATA\' -- Backup Location
SELECT @logpath = 'G:\SQL\LOG\' -- Backup Location
SELECT @bkpath = 'G:\backup\' -- Backup Location

DECLARE db_cursor CURSOR FOR
SELECT name
FROM sys.databases
WHERE name NOT IN ('master','model','msdb','tempdb')

OPEN db_cursor
FETCH NEXT FROM db_cursor INTO @name
WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0

BEGIN

    SET @InicioCadena= 'RESTORE DATABASE ' +@name+ ' FROM DISK='''+@bkpath+@name+'.bak'' WITH '

        DECLARE db_cursor2 CURSOR FOR SELECT f.name, f.type_desc,SUBSTRING(f.physical_name,LEN(f.physical_name)-2,3) AS exten
        FROM sys.master_files f
        INNER JOIN sys.databases d ON d.database_id = f.database_id
        WHERE d.name = @name
        order by 2 desc

        OPEN db_cursor2
        FETCH NEXT FROM db_cursor2 INTO @name_arch, @type_arch, @exten
        WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
        BEGIN

            IF @type_arch = 'ROWS'
                IF @exten = 'mdf'
                    SET @InicioCadena = @InicioCadena + 'MOVE '+''''+@name_arch+''' TO '+''''+@datapath+@name_arch+'_DATA.mdf'', '
                ELSE
                    SET @InicioCadena = @InicioCadena + 'MOVE '+''''+@name_arch+''' TO '+''''+@datapath+@name_arch+'_DATA.ndf'', '
            ELSE
                SET @InicioCadena = @InicioCadena + 'MOVE '+''''+@name_arch+''' TO '+''''+@logpath+@name_arch+'_LOG.log'', '

            FETCH NEXT FROM db_cursor2 INTO @name_arch, @type_arch, @exten
        END

        CLOSE db_cursor2
        DEALLOCATE db_cursor2
        PRINT SUBSTRING(@InicioCadena,1,LEN(@InicioCadena)-1)+';'
        
    FETCH NEXT FROM db_cursor INTO @name

END

CLOSE db_cursor
DEALLOCATE db_cursor
```

Gracias viejo Yei.